# Transferring Data b/w 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I want to transfer data of 2 columns from one table & 3 columns from another table to final output table(Contains 5 column).The problem is that there is no common column between A & B table.How can this work can be achieved in SSIS ..?

Comment: If there is now relation between tables A and B, how do you know how to fill the table C ?

Comment: So how do you know which rows from the first table should be matched up with the corresponding rows from the other table?

Answer (score 0):

Simple you know that these tables are some how related so what you're to do just add a column in both the table with proper entries to use as a key to join this and create a table with joining both table

Ex. As in sql =

```
create table C as 
(select a.one , a. two , B.one1 b.two1, b.three1 from a, b where a.new_column = b.new_column)
```

What you are to consider just insure what relation you have in mind that sholud be properly followed .

Answer (score 0):

use the "Union All" task. It combines the data from multiple inputs into one output (creates a new row from each data source)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you don't have a column that you can relate the two tables with. If you dont have a key column that you can relate the tables with, just import the data from the source in the order that it exists in the source and id it with an identity/ rank methods. And then you can use a join to relate the rows in the same order and import the data into the destination.

You can id it by using a temp dataset with a identity column or by using a ROW_NUMBER() function.